# Selenium: Order of Requests to Server Differs from real Browser

Tags: java, selenium, fiddler

I am using Selenium to execute a simple request to a certain url. I log the traffic to the server fia Fiddler2.

If I compare the traffic with the traffic of a real browser (In Private Browsing with Internet Explorer), the order of requests is different.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.tests.javaJunit4Webdriver;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class JavaJunit4WebdriverInternetExplorerWikiFacebook {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        try {

            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
            // Delete Browser Cache since IE does not open a clean profile
            // unlike Chrome & FireFox
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaJunit4Webdriver() {
        System.out.println("testJavaJunit4Webdriver");

        System.out.println("airdroid");
        driver.get("http://web.airdroid.com/");
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now.toString());
        for (long stop = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(7); stop > System
                .nanoTime();) {
        }
        System.out.println(new Date().toString());
        System.out.println("Wiki Facebook");

        baseUrl = "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook";

        driver.get(baseUrl);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown");

        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now.toString());
        for (long stop = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(7); stop > System
                .nanoTime();) {
        }
        System.out.println(new Date().toString());

        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

}
```

If I execute this test case, I get:

```
GET http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook
200 OK (text/html)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.flaggedRevs.basic%7Cext.gadget.CommonsDirekt%2CWikiMiniAtlas%7Cext.wikihiero%7Cmediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmw.PopUpMediaTransform%7Cskins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/css)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=site&only=styles&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/css)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Disambig-dark.svg/25px-Disambig-dark.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/geoiplookup
200 geoiplookup (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Facebook.svg/266px-Facebook.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/MarkZuckerberg.jpg/220px-MarkZuckerberg.jpg
200 OK (image/jpeg)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/common/images/magnify-clip.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki%2CSpinner%7Cjquery.triggerQueueCallback%2CloadingSpinner%2CmwEmbedUtil%7Cmw.MwEmbedSupport&only=scripts&skin=vector&version=20130218T165645Z
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.centralNotice.bannerController%7Cjquery.client%2Ccookie%2CmwExtension%7Cmediawiki.legacy.ajax%2Cwikibits%7Cmediawiki.notify%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.page.startup%7Cwikibase.client.init&skin=vector&version=20130307T025300Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:BannerRandom?userlang=de&sitename=Wikipedia&project=wikipedia&anonymous=true&bucket=0&country=DE&slot=2
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Flag_of_the_United_States_%28Pantone%29.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_United_States_%28Pantone%29.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Flag_of_Indonesia.svg/18px-Flag_of_Indonesia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Flag_of_Mexico.svg/18px-Flag_of_Mexico.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg/20px-Flag_of_India.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/20px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Flag_of_the_Vatican_City.svg/13px-Flag_of_the_Vatican_City.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Flag_of_%C3%85land.svg/20px-Flag_of_%C3%85land.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg/20px-Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Flag_of_Nauru.svg/20px-Flag_of_Nauru.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_Guernsey.svg/18px-Flag_of_Guernsey.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Flag_of_Monaco.svg/18px-Flag_of_Monaco.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/20px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Flag_of_the_Faroe_Islands.svg/18px-Flag_of_the_Faroe_Islands.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/20px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Flag_of_Niger.svg/20px-Flag_of_Niger.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:RecordImpression?result=hide&reason=empty&country=DE&userlang=de&project=wikipedia&db=dewiki&sitename=Wikipedia&bucket=0
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Flag_of_Gibraltar.svg/18px-Flag_of_Gibraltar.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Flag_of_Burundi.svg/18px-Flag_of_Burundi.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Tonga.svg/18px-Flag_of_Tonga.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/db/Flag_of_French_Polynesia.svg/20px-Flag_of_French_Polynesia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Flag_of_Latvia.svg/20px-Flag_of_Latvia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Flag_of_Moldova.svg/20px-Flag_of_Moldova.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Flag_of_the_Bahamas.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_Bahamas.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Flag_of_Yemen.svg/20px-Flag_of_Yemen.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Flag_of_Guinea.svg/20px-Flag_of_Guinea.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg/18px-Flag_of_Canada.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/20px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Flag_of_Vietnam.svg/20px-Flag_of_Vietnam.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Flag_of_Palestine.svg/20px-Flag_of_Palestine.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Flag_of_Cambodia.svg/20px-Flag_of_Cambodia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Flag_of_Azerbaijan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Azerbaijan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/12px-Commons-logo.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/images/wikimedia-button.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/vector/images/search-ltr.png?303-4
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=skins.vector&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=site&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Wikipedia-logo-v2-de.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Flag_of_Turkmenistan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Turkmenistan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.UserBuckets%7Cext.articleFeedbackv5.startup%7Cext.flaggedRevs.advanced%7Cext.gadget.CommonsDirekt%2CWikiMiniAtlas%7Cjquery.articleFeedbackv5.verify%7Cjquery.autoEllipsis%2CcheckboxShiftClick%2CclickTracking%2CdelayedBind%2Chidpi%2ChighlightText%2Cjson%2CmakeCollapsible%2Cmw-jump%2Cplaceholder%2Csuggestions%2CtabIndex%7Cmediawiki.api%2Chidpi%2CsearchSuggest%2Cuser%7Cmediawiki.page.ready%7Cmobile.desktop%7Cmw.MwEmbedSupport.style%7Cmw.PopUpMediaTransform&skin=vector&version=20130307T025253Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.vector.collapsibleNav%2CcollapsibleTabs%2CeditWarning%7Cjquery.collapsibleTabs&skin=vector&version=20130307T025311Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=jquery.ui.button%2Ccore%2Cdialog%2Cdraggable%2Cmouse%2Cposition%2Cresizable%2Cwidget&skin=vector&version=20130218T165324Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/favicon/wikipedia.ico
200 OK (image/x-icon)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Wikiminiatlas.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript&smaxage=21600&maxage=86400
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Monobook-bullet-star-gray.png
200 OK (image/png)
```

If I execute the request in an "in private session" of the internet Explorer, the order of execution is different.

```
GET http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook
200 OK (text/html)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.flaggedRevs.basic%7Cext.gadget.CommonsDirekt%2CWikiMiniAtlas%7Cext.wikihiero%7Cmediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmw.PopUpMediaTransform%7Cskins.vector&only=styles&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/css)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=site&only=styles&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/css)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/geoiplookup
200 geoiplookup (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Disambig-dark.svg/25px-Disambig-dark.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Facebook.svg/266px-Facebook.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/MarkZuckerberg.jpg/220px-MarkZuckerberg.jpg
200 OK (image/jpeg)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/common/images/magnify-clip.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki%2CSpinner%7Cjquery.triggerQueueCallback%2CloadingSpinner%2CmwEmbedUtil%7Cmw.MwEmbedSupport&only=scripts&skin=vector&version=20130218T165645Z
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.centralNotice.bannerController%7Cjquery.client%2Ccookie%2CmwExtension%7Cmediawiki.legacy.ajax%2Cwikibits%7Cmediawiki.notify%2Cutil%7Cmediawiki.page.startup%7Cwikibase.client.init&skin=vector&version=20130307T025300Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:BannerRandom?userlang=de&sitename=Wikipedia&project=wikipedia&anonymous=true&bucket=1&country=DE&slot=7
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e2/Flag_of_the_United_States_%28Pantone%29.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_United_States_%28Pantone%29.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Flag_of_Indonesia.svg/18px-Flag_of_Indonesia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg/20px-Flag_of_India.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Flag_of_Mexico.svg/18px-Flag_of_Mexico.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Flag_of_Brazil.svg/20px-Flag_of_Brazil.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Flag_of_the_Vatican_City.svg/13px-Flag_of_the_Vatican_City.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Flag_of_%C3%85land.svg/20px-Flag_of_%C3%85land.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg/20px-Flag_of_American_Samoa.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Flag_of_Nauru.svg/20px-Flag_of_Nauru.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_Guernsey.svg/18px-Flag_of_Guernsey.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Flag_of_Iceland.svg/20px-Flag_of_Iceland.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Flag_of_Monaco.svg/18px-Flag_of_Monaco.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/Flag_of_Turkmenistan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Turkmenistan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Flag_of_Gibraltar.svg/18px-Flag_of_Gibraltar.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Flag_of_Burundi.svg/18px-Flag_of_Burundi.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Tonga.svg/18px-Flag_of_Tonga.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:RecordImpression?result=hide&reason=empty&country=DE&userlang=de&project=wikipedia&db=dewiki&sitename=Wikipedia&bucket=1
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Flag_of_Latvia.svg/20px-Flag_of_Latvia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Flag_of_the_Faroe_Islands.svg/18px-Flag_of_the_Faroe_Islands.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Brunei.svg/20px-Flag_of_Brunei.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Flag_of_Moldova.svg/20px-Flag_of_Moldova.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Flag_of_the_Bahamas.svg/20px-Flag_of_the_Bahamas.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Afghanistan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Flag_of_Yemen.svg/20px-Flag_of_Yemen.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Flag_of_Guinea.svg/20px-Flag_of_Guinea.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Flag_of_Canada.svg/18px-Flag_of_Canada.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Flag_of_Denmark.svg/20px-Flag_of_Denmark.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Flag_of_Vietnam.svg/20px-Flag_of_Vietnam.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Flag_of_Palestine.svg/20px-Flag_of_Palestine.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Flag_of_Cambodia.svg/20px-Flag_of_Cambodia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Flag_of_Azerbaijan.svg/20px-Flag_of_Azerbaijan.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/12px-Commons-logo.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/vector/images/search-ltr.png?303-4
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/images/wikimedia-button.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/static-1.21wmf10/skins/common/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=skins.vector&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=site&only=scripts&skin=vector&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Flag_of_Niger.svg/20px-Flag_of_Niger.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Wikipedia-logo-v2-de.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/db/Flag_of_French_Polynesia.svg/20px-Flag_of_French_Polynesia.svg.png
200 OK (image/png)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.UserBuckets%7Cext.articleFeedbackv5.startup%7Cext.flaggedRevs.advanced%7Cext.gadget.CommonsDirekt%2CWikiMiniAtlas%7Cjquery.articleFeedbackv5.verify%7Cjquery.autoEllipsis%2CcheckboxShiftClick%2CclickTracking%2CdelayedBind%2Chidpi%2ChighlightText%2Cjson%2CmakeCollapsible%2Cmw-jump%2Cplaceholder%2Csuggestions%2CtabIndex%7Cmediawiki.api%2Chidpi%2CsearchSuggest%2Cuser%7Cmediawiki.page.ready%7Cmobile.desktop%7Cmw.MwEmbedSupport.style%7Cmw.PopUpMediaTransform&skin=vector&version=20130307T025253Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=ext.vector.collapsibleNav%2CcollapsibleTabs%2CeditWarning%7Cjquery.collapsibleTabs&skin=vector&version=20130307T025311Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/de.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&lang=de&modules=jquery.ui.button%2Ccore%2Cdialog%2Cdraggable%2Cmouse%2Cposition%2Cresizable%2Cwidget&skin=vector&version=20130218T165324Z&*
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Wikiminiatlas.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript&smaxage=21600&maxage=86400
200 OK (text/javascript)

GET http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Monobook-bullet-star-gray.png
200 OK (image/png)
```

This differences occur also when comparing Selenium-2-Chrome <-> Chrome browser and Selenium-2-Firefox <-> Firefox browser.

Is there any possibility to make the selenium session exactly as the one with the "natural browsing"?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sysout/Syserror is the following:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.29.1.0
Listening on port 15656
Mrz 07, 2013 7:15:42 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Mrz 07, 2013 7:15:42 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
testJavaJunit4Webdriver
airdroid
Thu Mar 07 19:15:44 CET 2013
Thu Mar 07 19:15:51 CET 2013
Wiki Facebook
tearDown
Thu Mar 07 19:15:55 CET 2013
Thu Mar 07 19:16:02 CET 2013
```

My libraries are:

```
27.02.2013  15:54           345.048 apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           242.154 bsh-1.3.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           324.238 cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           232.771 commons-codec-1.6.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           575.389 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            52.543 commons-exec-1.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           173.587 commons-io-2.2.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           299.994 commons-jxpath-1.3.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           315.805 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            60.686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           281.014 cssparser-0.9.8.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         2.189.111 guava-14.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            45.024 hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            53.070 hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         1.230.705 htmlunit-2.11.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         1.009.889 htmlunit-core-js-2.11.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           427.022 httpclient-4.2.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           223.374 httpcore-4.2.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            26.598 httpmime-4.2.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           101.578 ini4j-0.5.2.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            56.533 jcommander-1.29.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           125.727 jetty-websocket-8.1.8.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         1.006.639 jna-3.4.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           913.435 jna-platform-3.4.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            37.875 json-20080701.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           245.039 junit-dep-4.11.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           124.478 nekohtml-1.9.17.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         1.106.629 netty-3.5.7.Final.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         4.060.747 operadriver-1.2.jar
27.02.2013  15:54             8.597 phantomjsdriver-1.0.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           450.284 protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54            15.808 sac-1.3.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         3.749.497 selenium-java-2.31.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           278.281 serializer-2.7.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           813.398 testng-6.8.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         3.176.148 xalan-2.7.1.jar
27.02.2013  15:54         1.363.159 xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
27.02.2013  15:54           220.536 xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

Comment: That's just the order in which the browser is loading the resources on the page.  It should not have any impact on what you're testing.  Are you sure this matters?  If yes, why?

Comment: Can I ask why does this matter?

Comment: In general, I wander, why there is this difference. The owner of the web server is then easily able to tell whether just any user is doing the access or it was my access. My aim is to reduce the fingerprint that makes my access to the server unique. Think of scenarios where in e. g. totalitarian regimes the authorities are able to find you just because your web access is always different to the rest of the users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the load on the system, the availability of idle connections, DNS lookup times, etc, you will see different orderings of requests from any client.

As a consequence, looking at the requests from a pure "ordering" perspective isn't very reliable.

You haven't provided any timestamps to show *when* the given requests are made. For all we know, all of these requests were sent in the same millisecond, and you'd get different results if you reloaded the page in the browser.

An article I wrote a while back:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx explains how "lookahead" parsers cause different request ordering across different browsers and different versions of the same browser.